# TypeError on load .js

Tags: javascript, function, typeerror

I have code before , but console showing TypeError: $ is not function on line 1 :(
Can you help me with reason? Thanks!

```
$('.day.event').parent().each(function (i, e) {
var element = $(e);

var prevElement=$(e).prev();
var hasPrevElement = true;
if(prevElement.size() === 0) {
    var prevRow = element.parent().prev();
    if(prevRow.size() === 0) {
        hasPrevElement = false;
    }
    prevElement = prevRow.children().last();
}

var nextElement=$(e).next();
var hasNextElement = true;
if(nextElement.size() === 0) {
    var nextRow = element.parent().next();
    if(nextRow.size() === 0) {
        hasNextElement = false;
    }
    nextElement = nextRow.children().first();
}

if(hasPrevElement && prevElement.children().first().attr("class").indexOf("event") === -1 || !hasPrevElement) {
    element.addClass('first-day')
}

if(hasNextElement && nextElement.children().first().attr("class").indexOf("event") === -1) {
    nextElement.addClass('after-event');
}
```

});

Comment: You need to load jQuery before your script.

Comment: But does not work from version 2.2.4 up

Answer (score 0):

You should import  jQuery library before the code above as @Wendelin said or check the path of your file